# Excepciones con java y mysql

Tags: java, mysql, excepciones

Buenos dias, tardes, noches.

Quiero hacer una excepción para que cuando alguien se quiera registrar con una cédula o un email ya existente, arroje un aviso que diga que no se puede porque tal ya existe en la bd, y lo estoy intentando hacer de esta manera pero mi problema es que no quiere entrar en el if ni en el else if, e intente imprimir en pantalla la variable err y errCedula y son exactamente iguales, entonces no se porque no entra en el if, agradeceria mucho alguna ayuda, me dicen si necesitan alguna otra info para que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

```
try {
    //codigo
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        int resp = 0; 
        String errCedula = "Duplicate entry '"+ i.getCedula() + "' for key 'clientes.cedula_UNIQUE'";
        String errEmail = "Duplicate entry '"+i.getCorreo()+"' for key 'clientes.correo_UNIQUE'";
        String err = e.getMessage();
        
//--------------En este if tengo el problema, porque no entra ---------------       
        if (err == errCedula) {
            resp = 2;
            return resp;
        }else if (err == errEmail){
            resp = 3;
            return resp;
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            return resp; 
        }
```

Comment: Si la excepcion no ocurre no podras entrar al catch.

Comment: @Japv el dice que si entra al error pero no a los condicionales

Comment: Lo mejor es no depender del texto de `e.getMessage() ` porque puede cambiar en un futuro, o simplemente porque es más plausible tener errores al programar. Lo mejor es depender de status codes o sql states. Esos no tenderán a cambiar, y son más fáciles de manejar.

Comment: Estoy usando el `e.getMessage()` porque intente hacerlo con el statusCode pero me arroja el mismo codigo en los dos errores y yo quiero mostrar un aviso diferente para cada uno, entonces por eso lo hago con el getMessage porque me arroja un diferente resultado para cada error, nose si me hice entender, pero gracias lo tendre en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está ocurriendo te lo voy a desglosar en varios puntos.

1. Si no se genera la excepción, el código no entra en el bloque catch.
2. Asumiendo que genera la excepción, lo que indicas evaluar en tus bloques if es que si **err** y **errCedula** son de la misma instancia de un objeto. Siempre será false porque lo que tú quieres evaluar es su contenido, no si son el mismo objeto.
3. Dado que son Strings y no variables primitivas, para evaluar el contenido debes de hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
err.equals(errCedula)
```

El método **.equals()** es un método que tiene la clase String y lo que hace es precisamente lo que estás buscando. Compara dos cadenas y si las dos cadenas contienen los mismos caracteres en el mismo orden, devuelve true. Si no, devolverá false.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración amigo, y si entraba en el catch, el problema estaba en que no entraba en el condicional, al intentar debuguearlo vi que los valores eran iguales pero no entendia porque no entraba al if si eran iguales, pero ya me quedo mas claro, gracias bro.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no intentas usar en vez de `==` un `.equals()`:

```
err.equals(errCedula){
    resp = 2;
    return resp;
}else if (err.equals(errEmail)){
    resp = 3;
    return resp;
}
```

Ese problema es muy común.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, si era cambiarle `==` a  `.equals()`, gracias

Comment: De nada , no olvides marcar como mejor respuesta, la que te haya ayudado :)